# android block collapsing toolbar, translucent status cuts half of toolbar

Tags: android, xamarin.android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a problem with the collapsing toolbar and backdrop image. I want my backdrop image to be overlapped by status bar when it is visible at home fragment, but I need to block the collapsing toolbar at every other fragment.

I tried `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in every possible combination, didn't work.

When I set styles v21 
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>`

My app looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/otGXy.jpg

Then when I set `TranslucentStatus to true` I get my desired effect at home fragment but toolbars at every other fragment are broken what you can see at screens posted below.

Another problem shows up when I collapse the image and go to any other fragment, all toolbar icons disappear. Problem might be caused by blocking collapse but I'm not sure, can someone suggest a different method to block collapsing toolbar at other fragments so I can test it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YpbD.jpg

Here is my main.xml layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainContent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/backdrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

Styles-v21

```
<style name="Theme.Ecologic" parent="Base.Theme.Ecologic">
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Simple code i found at stack used to enable / disable collapsing toolbar at other fragments

```
public void EnableCollapse()
{
    _backdrop.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}

public void DisableCollapse()
{
    _backdrop.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
```

**@SOLVED**
After few hours I have found solution. Problem was caused by changing the visibility of backdrop image. I modified Enable and Disable Collapse methods and now everything works fine. I can block toolbar expansion at any time.

```
public void EnableCollapse()
    {
        _appBarLayout.SetExpanded(true, false);
        _appBarLayout.Activated = true;
        var lparams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)_appBarLayout.LayoutParameters;
        var behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
        behavior.SetDragCallback(new MyDragCallBack(true));
        lparams.Behavior = behavior;
    }

    public void DisableCollapse(View view)
    {
        _appBarLayout.SetExpanded(false,false);
        _appBarLayout.Activated = false;
        var lparams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) _appBarLayout.LayoutParameters;
        var behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
        behavior.SetDragCallback(new MyDragCallBack(false));
        lparams.Behavior = behavior;
        if (view != null)
        {
            ViewCompat.SetNestedScrollingEnabled(view, false);
        }
    }

    public class MyDragCallBack : AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback
    {
        private readonly bool _enabled;

        public MyDragCallBack(bool enable)
        {
            _enabled = enable;
        }
        public override bool CanDrag(AppBarLayout p0)
        {
            return _enabled;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually you need to add (android:fitsSystemWindows="true") to (CoordinatorLayout ) and (AppBarLayout) and to (ImageView)  -- Try that

Comment: and to (CollapsingToolbarLayout) -- you may not need it in (ImageView) -- but try and see